# sort without Array.Sort

Tags: c#

I just barely understood how to use if statement and "for loop." In addition right now I have to do this

> Sort the integer elements within the array from lowest (element 0) to highest (element 4). Do not use the preexisting Array.Sort method; code your own.

This is a homework problem and I don't even know where to start. Can somebody walk me through this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i;
        double power = 0, sum = 0;
        int[] mArray = new int[5];


        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Number Between 10 and 50 \nMake sure all of your Number entered correctly \notherwise you will need to enter everything again ");


        for (i = 0; i < mArray.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter your Number.");
            mArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (mArray[i] >= 50 || mArray[i] <= 10)
            {
                i--;
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter numbers only between 10 and 50.");

            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i < mArray.Length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + (mArray[i]);
        }

        double mean = sum / mArray.Length;

        for (i = 0; i < mArray.Length; i++)
        {
            power += Math.Pow((mArray[i] - mean), 2);
        }

        double rMean = power / (mArray.Length - 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Mean {0}", mean);
        Console.WriteLine("Variance {0}", rMean);

        Console.WriteLine("Here is sorted numbers");




        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193233/sort-the-integers-without-using-sort-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many sorting algorithms you can try like [Insertion Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/insertion-sort)
[Selection Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/selection-sort),
[Bubble Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort),
[Shell Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/shell-sort),
[Merge Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/merge-sort),
[Heap Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/heap-sort),
[Quick Sort](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort),
And many Others.

Comment: or listen in class your teacher probably has dropped a few hints :-)